# Conversion Stacked Bar Chart to Stacked 100 Bar Chart in AChartEngine

Tags: java, android, bar-chart, achartengine

I am working on an android application in which i am using AChartEngine as Charting Library. It provides Stacked Bar Chart (Vertical Bars) in Demo and i want it to convert to Stacked 100 Bar Chart (Vertical Bars). How can it be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AChartEngine doesn't provide a Stacked 100 bar charts feature out of the box.

However, you can push the data to it such as you get to the needed look. The idea is that the last series that you add will have to have all the values equal to the maximum value.

Comment: yeah i thought about it but the problem will be that it would have to display another extra status in Legend (Bottom) which would not be right. Any chance that i can hide individual elements of legend?

Comment: You can hide the legend entirely, but not the items individually.

Comment: Hey Dan would Stacked 100 Column Chart will be added in the furthur release of AChartEngine library?

Comment: @FahadAbidJanjua how did you convert to 100 column chart, can you please explain a bit??